# How do I install VMWare Workstation (6.5.5) on ubuntu 10.10

Tags: vmware, ubuntu-10.10

When I try to install I get error:

> VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle
>
> VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle: line 108: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'
>
> VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle: line 108: `'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two possibilities:

a) You tried to execute the .bundle as a shell script (i.e. sh VMware-Workstation-6.5.5-328052.x86_64.bundle)
In this case chmod u+x it, then execute it ./

b) You downloaded it with firefox, in this case for some strange reason the file is only 20k in size an does not work. I ran into this problem yesterday. Downloading it with Opera worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

The Vmware Website has a new download manager plugin for firefox (and possibly other browsers) that is the reason for the 20K size. Opt to download using your browser to download and you should be able to get the full installer that way.